# template literals giving different answer

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, for-loop, template-literals

I'am javascript beginner trying to code to improve myself, at the moment trying to learn 'template literals' and for some reason getting different answer by putting inside 'template literals'. Here is my code :

```js
const foodArray = [
  { name: 'Burrito' },
  { name: 'Pizza' },
  { name: 'Burger' },
  { name: 'Pasta' }
];
for (let i = 0; i < foodArray.length; i++) {
  console.log(`i value: ${i} | Food Name:`, foodArray[i]);
  

}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

so now i'm putting  'foodArray[i]' inside 'template literals' like this ' ${foodArray[i] ' but it is giving me '[object Object]', shouldn't it give same result ? maybe i'm doing something wrong here

```js
const foodArray = [
  { name: 'Burrito' },
  { name: 'Pizza' },
  { name: 'Burger' },
  { name: 'Pasta' }
];
for (let i = 0; i < foodArray.length; i++) {
  console.log(`i value: ${i} | Food Name: ${foodArray[i]}`);
  

}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: this is just a difference in how a template literal stringifies an object vs how the implementation of console.log does it.  template literal calls `toString()` on it. console.log is using JSON.sringify or something.

Comment: @bryan60 could you write answer to fixing this possibly ?

Comment: just do `${JSON.stringify(foodArray[i])}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`console.log` is going to do things differently than the template literal. the `console.log` will send the actual object reference to the console client and the particular console client will decide from there how to present that object, they all do it slightly differently. template literals will always call the objects `.toString()` method. some console clients just call the `.toString()` method as well, some use `JSON.stringify`, some use sophisticated object explorers, the SO console client uses some method to produce "pretty" JSON.

you can get it closer to the console representation or at least make it consistent by using `JSON.stringify`:

```
console.log(`i value: ${i} | Food Name: ${JSON.stringify(foodArray[i])}`);
```

but generally, in real world programming, you won't be sending objects to a template literal, so this isn't a huge concern in most applications.